# How to change the font(size) for verbatim in ltxdoc

Tags: verbatim, documentation

The MWE shows what I mean. Using class article I can change the verbatim font. Using ltxdoc nothing happens. I looked in doc.sty and ltxdoc.cls but found nothing. Why does the verbatim environment font setting behave differently in ltxdoc anyway?

```
%\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{ltxdoc}
\makeatletter
 \newcommand{\verbatimfont}[1]{\def\verbatim@font{#1}}%
\makeatother

\verbatimfont{\normalfont\rmfamily\Large}

\begin{document}
This is normal text
\begin{verbatim}
This is verbatim text
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `verbatimbox` package, which provides an optional argument for doing all sorts of settings, including font size.

```
%\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
This is normal text
\begin{verbnobox}[\LARGE]
This is verbatim text
\end{verbnobox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

## `\MacroFont`

Maybe, you are looking for `\MacroFont` of package `doc` (default font size defined by `\MacroFont` is `\small`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{ltxdoc}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\MacroFont{\Large}
\g@addto@macro\AltMacroFont{\Large}% slanted verbatim
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is normal text
\begin{verbatim}
This is verbatim text
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

`\MacroFont` is used for environments `verbatim`, `verbatim*`, `macrocode`, and macros `\PrintMacroName`, `\PrintDescribeMacro`, `\PrintDescribeEnv`, and `\PrintEnvName`.

## Patching `verbatim`

Another solution is to patch environment `verbatim`. The following example shows it for `verbatim` and `verbatim*`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{ltxdoc}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\verbatim{\MacroFont}{\MacroFont\Large}{}{%
  \errmessage{Cannot patch enviroment `verbatim'.}%
}
\expandafter
\patchcmd\csname verbatim*\endcsname{\MacroFont}{\MacroFont\Large}{}{%
  \errmessage{Cannot patch environment `verbatim*'.}%
}

\begin{document}
This is normal text
\begin{verbatim}
This is verbatim text
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Heiko for your answer. Is there no way to change _only_ the font for the `verbatim` environment?

Comment: Sorry, I saw your 'patching' solution after I wrote my simple work-around. In the meantime I prefer (and implemented) the `verbnobox` solution. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple working solution as shown below.
Now only the `verbatim` environment is affected.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{ltxdoc}
\begin{document}
This is normal text
{
\renewcommand{\MacroFont}{\ttfamily\large}

\begin{verbatim}
This is verbatim text
\end{verbatim}
}
\end{document}
```